# How to enable mouse click signature feature in docu sign

Tags: docusignapi

I am working on SOAP UI to test Docusign methods. I am getting emails and attachement with signature(anchor tab). But I am getting only signatures to be selected but not able to
allow user to sign using mouse. How to enable this feature?

Thanks.

Comment: The recipient can see the Signature tab during their signing session, but can't click on it to apply their signature?  I've never observed this behavior -- if the signature tab is visible to the signer during their signing session, they should be able to click on it to sign -- there's no special setting that I'm aware of to enable this behavior.  What browser are you using as the signer?  Have you tried using another type of browser, to see if the issue reproduces there?

Comment: Kim I believe they are talking about the Draw vs. Adopt signature options.  This is an account level setting that needs to be altered...

Comment: Good call Ergin -- re-reading the question just now, I think your assessment of the issue is spot on.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you're talking about is how DocuSign gives signers the ability to adopt one of the default signature styles or you can draw your signature using the mouse.  This is an **account level** setting that needs to be enabled in your account.

When your signers are signing if they do not have the ability to draw in their signature using the mouse, then most likely they have "Disable Draw Signature" checked in your account settings.

To resolve try the following:

```
1. Login to the Console.
2. Go to Preferences -> Features page.
3. There should be a "Signature Adoption Configuration" hyperlink.  (if not contact your Account Manager to have that enabled)
4. Open the Signature Adoption Config screen by clicking the link.
5. Un-check the "Disable Draw Signature" option.
```

Then send another signature request and your recipients should have the ability to adopt their signature or draw their own.

[image]

Comment: Before posting this question, I checked all those options. By default it was unchecked only but I am not able to check the Diasable style selection option.It is unchecked by default and not allowing me to check it.

Comment: I'm talking about the Disable Draw Signature option though. Aren't you saying that the problem is that your signers can adopt one of the predefined signatures but they can NOT draw their own with the mouse?  If so, I thought that the Disable Draw Signature option was checked in your account.  If it's not checked then something else is going on...